# Lecture Slide Clarification: Computable in Polynomial Time

Tags: algorithm

[image]

**I** = input

**|I|** = number of inputs

**A(I) = P(I)** means algorithm **A** gives the required output for problem **P** on input **I**.

Why does **Time(A, I) <= |I|^2** not apply for small **I**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity):

> ...Since this function is generally difficult to compute exactly, and
>   the running time is usually not critical for small input, one focuses
>   commonly on the behavior of the complexity when the input size
>   increases, that is on the asymptotic behavior of the complexity.

In the slide the wording might be a bit misleading, it's not that it doesn't apply, but more accurately: it *may* not apply for small input.

Comment: When would it not apply? I would think Time(A, I) <= |I|^2  is always true no matter how small the input is, if P is computable in polynomial time.

Comment: @NoName Take merge sort for example, we know that the big O is O(nlogn), but if you'll count the number of steps required to sort an array of the size of 3, for example, using merge sort, you'll see that it could take more than 5 steps which means, more than nlogn steps. We don't really care about that since for small input the error is not meaningful, what we *do* care about is the asymptotic behavior (when the input increases).

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh